# How to add Enable/Disable extention functionality in admin side in custom extention magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin, extensions, enable-disable

We want to create one custom extension which has functionality in admin side for Enable/Disable.
Any one help me how to add this functionality in my custom extension.

Comment: How you want to use this setting is the main thing? Custom Plugin, Events, Preferences still will be executed.

Comment: We use this custom plugin only for overwrite phtml files of product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to Create a System.xml in the folder like etc/adminhtml/System.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
     <system>
        <tab id="ModuleName" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
           <label>ModuleName</label>
       </tab>

      <section id="customproductdata" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Custom Product Data</label>
                <tab>ModuleName</tab>
    <resource>ModuleName_Customproductdata::customproductdata_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
           <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Enable</label>
         <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
     </field>
   </group>
 </section>
</system>
```

Than Create Config.xml file as the Same location and Put Below code into that.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
 <default>
     <customproductdata>
       <general>
           <enable>1</enable>
              <title>ModuleName Customproductdata</title>
         </general>
     </customproductdata>
 </default>
</config>
```

Now you will See this custom Yes no option in Magento 2 admin section.

Comment: Thanks. It's work perfectly.

Comment: If answer was correct or satisfy with answer please approved answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create system.xml in your module.

> etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Add the following content to have enable disable module configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="yourmodulename" translate="label" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <resource>Vendor_YourModuleName::configuration</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable Module</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

Comment: In admin site where this setting show ? Enable or Disable

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in `etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<group id="general" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="20">
<field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1">
    <label>Enable</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>    
</field>
</group>
```

Using below code in helper file.

```
public function isEnabled()
{
    return (boolean) $this->getConfig('namespace_modulename/general/enable');
}
```

And call this function whenever you want. 
That's it, i hope it helps!

Comment: If any possible way to create extension with enable/disable option ?

Comment: I have a post answer for that. but I think you are confused. can you explain more what do you want exactly?

Comment: we want to create one custom extension. Which in manage from admin side. It means any person enable/disable it from admin side. Main purpose for create this extension is overwrite phtml files for product view page.